# How can I redirect all wordpress post to custom permalink

Tags: wordpress

I have website in wordpress. I have created its Permalink structure like this

```
domain.com/postname/post_id
```

Now I want to redirect all

```
domain.com/postname/
```

to

```
domain.com/postname/post_id
```

Please suggest me how can I do this.

Comment: Not clear your question. Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
Admin section -> Settings -> Permalinks -> select Custom structure
```

and write

```
/%postname%/%post_id%
```

to the text field